# kendo chart export to excel with image as well as data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a kendo chart where i can export the image from javascript side but it will ask for save the image but i wanted to store the image in particular path without asking and then export the image into excel and then add some data along with the image.Please help me how to acheive this functionality.

Comment: Please help me on this issue

Comment: Can someone help me out on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/export ? 
I think you can save the chart in either of the three mentioned formats.
And,i guess saving path can be mentioned in the same.